# Display JSON data in Cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, java, json, gson, cytoscape.js

I am generating a programmatically a graph in a Java Web Application that should be send to  Cytoscape.js (2.7.10) in order to show it there. To transport the data from the Application to Cytoscape.js I build a JSON Object with gson (2.8.1).  The data that arrives at the JavaScript Part looks as follows:

```
{"elements":[{"nodes":[{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"a","name":"Eins"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"b","name":"Zwei"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"c","name":"Drei"}},{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":"d","name":"Vier"}}]},{"edges":[{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"e","name":"1-2","source":"a","target":"b"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"f","name":"2-3","source":"b","target":"c"}},{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"g","name":"2-4","source":"b","target":"d"}}]}]}
```

Setting up the cytoscape “window” looks like this

```
return function(callbackuri, inputdata, divname, title, colorstr) {
    console.log("CytoScape Test ver:0.1.9");
    console.log("Data String send to cyto * "+inputdata+" *");
    var cy = cytoscape({
        container : $('#cy'),
        elements: JSON.parse(inputdata),
        style: [
            {
                selector: 'node',
                style: {
                    'label': 'data(name)',
                    'width': '60px',
                    'height': '60px',
                    'color': 'blue',
                    'background-fit': 'contain',
                    'background-clip': 'none'
                }
            }
            , {
                selector: 'edge',
                style: {
                    'text-background-color': 'yellow',
                    'text-background-opacity': 0.4,
                    'width': '6px',
                    'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
                    'control-point-step-size': '140px'
                }
            }]
    });

    //
    cy.layout(concentric_options);
    cy.fit();
})
```

I also tried to skip the setup via elements: JSON.parse(inputdata) after the setup and before the layout allkind of options.

Like

```
var eles = cy.add(JSON.parse(inputdata)); 
cy.json(JSON.parse(inputdata));
cy.json(JSON.stringify(inputdata));
cy.add( JSON.parse( inputdata ) )
cy.load(JSON.parse(inputdata));
cy.load(inputdata);
```

None of them work. Most of the times I will be presented with one big node that I can zoom and pan but that is clearly not what is suppose to be there.

Funnily I can setup a Graph manually if I add the Data after the setup and before the Layout via this function call:

```
var eles = cy.add([ {
    group : "nodes",
    data : {
        id : "n0",
        name : "A",
        weight : 75
    }
}, {
    group : "nodes",
    data : {
        id : "n1",
        name : "B",
        weight : 75

    }
},
….
```

Anyone any idea?

Cheers

Janko

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid.  Look at the spec: http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/elements-json

`elements` is either an array or an object -- not one wrapped in the other.